# Title in header for Multiple TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I know a method to create a header title for a single UITableView:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
     return @"My Title"
}
```

But How can i set the title for Multiple UITableViews with different names?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: So you have more than one uitableviews on a single view right?

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman: yes!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
  if(tableView==myFirstTable)//myfirstTable is the IBOutlet of the tableView that is connected with your .xib
   {
 return @"Table1"
   }

  else
     return @"Table2" 

}
```

hope the above code can help you.

Comment: i need to display the title at a time on both tables!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use same method:

but when creating tableview just assign tag to it as follows:
tablebview1.tag = 1;

tableview2.tag = 2 and so on..

and in this method you can check for tableview tag value and create header.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     switch(tableView.tag){
        case:0{
         //Based on section provide title.
           break;
        }
        case:1{
         //Based on section provide title.
           break;
        }
        case:2{
        //Based on section provide title.
           break;
        }

}
```